# How do I over-come the Python error "loader_get_template is not defined"?

Tags: python, django-views

Need help with the following Python (Django) code:

If you look at the third line (3) the "loader.get_template"
MS Visual Studio is complaining that "loader" is not defined and the Python server is complaining as well

NOTE: The code is typed per the Django website documentation page

just below are my import statements:

```
from imp import load_source
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Question
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Template

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by("pub_date")[:5]
    template = loader.get_template("polls/index.html")
    context = {
    "lastest_question_list": latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.rendar(context, request))
```

I have tried:
- load.get_template
- *loader*.get_template; and just
- get_template

I'm expecting the web page to load --- the server will not load the page

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\onefi\mysite\polls\views.py", line 16, in index
    template = loader.get_template("polls/index.html")
NameError: name 'loader' is not defined
[11/Oct/2023 10:42:46] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 500 68410
```

**Docs URL:**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: Please provide the *full* traceback.

Comment: Can you share where this has been defined in the documentation. This likely is then a typo that can be fixed.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Willem see the bottom of post for Traceback...thks for the help

Comment: @SamMcGraw: the import statement is in the sample: `from django.template import loader`. You should not use `from django.template.loader import get_template`, since then `get_template` is in the scope, not `loader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are here doing manually has already been implemented, with the [**`render(…)`** shortcut <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

```
from django.shorcuts import render


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'lastest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

If we inspect the [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d21ab70223dcbdc5a2603a88945147f2f780deee/django/shortcuts.py#L17-L25), we see that this is imported as:

```
from django.template import loader
```

But it makes not much sense to implement low level code again: abstracting away makes code shorter, and easier to maintain.